# Inserting into a Cassandra DB is slow even with execute_concurrent()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cassandra, datastax-python-driver

I am trying to insert a pandas dataframe into cassandra. I am using the execute_concurrent, but I don't see any improvement. It is taking almost 5s per row insertions. There are 14k rows so at this rate it will take more than 15 hours. I have 12 GB RAM with 2 CPU cores. How fast can I run this operation? I've tried with different concurrency numbers but without any success. Following is my code-:

```
from flask import session
import yaml
import pandas as pd
import argparse
from get_data import read_params
import cassandra
from cassandra.concurrent import execute_concurrent_with_args, execute_concurrent
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, ExecutionProfile
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
import sys
import time

def progressbar(it, prefix="", size=60, out=sys.stdout): # Python3.3+
    count = len(it)
    def show(j):
        x = int(size*j/count)
        print("{}[{}{}] {}/{}".format(prefix, u"█"*x, "."*(size-x), j, count), 
                end='\r', file=out, flush=True)
    show(0)
    for i, item in enumerate(it):
        yield item
        show(i+1)
    print("\n", flush=True, file=out)

def cassandraDBLoad(config_path):
    try:
        config = read_params(config_path)

        execution_profile = ExecutionProfile(request_timeout=10)
        cassandra_config = {'secure_connect_bundle': "path"}
        auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(
                "client_id",
                "client_secret"
                )
        cluster = Cluster(cloud=cassandra_config, auth_provider=auth_provider)
        session = cluster.connect()
        session.default_timeout = None
        connect_db = session.execute("select release_version from system.local")
        set_keyspace = session.set_keyspace("Keyspace Name")
        
        table_ = "big_mart"
        define_columns = "Item_Identifier varchar PRIMARY KEY, Item_Weight varchar, Item_Fat_Content varchar, Item_Visibility varchar,  Item_Type varchar, Item_MRP varchar, Outlet_Identifier varchar, Outlet_Establishment_Year varchar, Outlet_Size varchar, Outlet_Location_type varchar, Outlet_Type varchar, Item_Outlet_Sales varchar, source varchar"
        drop_table = f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_}"
        drop_result = session.execute(drop_table)
        create_table = f"CREATE TABLE {table_}({define_columns});"
        table_result = session.execute(create_table)
    
        train = pd.read_csv("train_source")
        test = pd.read_csv("test_source")
    
        #Combine test and train into one file
        train['source']='train'
        test['source']='test'
        df = pd.concat([train, test],ignore_index=True)
        df = df.fillna('NA')
        
        columns = "Item_Identifier, Item_Weight, Item_Fat_Content, Item_Visibility, Item_Type, Item_MRP, Outlet_Identifier, Outlet_Establishment_Year, Outlet_Size, Outlet_Location_Type, Outlet_Type, Item_Outlet_Sales, source"
        insert_qry = f"INSERT INTO {table_}({columns}) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        statement = session.prepare(insert_qry)
        parameters = [
            (str(df.iat[i,0]), str(df.iat[i,1]), str(df.iat[i,2]), str(df.iat[i,3]), 
             str(df.iat[i,4]), str(df.iat[i,5]), str(df.iat[i,6]), str(df.iat[i,7]), 
             str(df.iat[i,8]), str(df.iat[i,9]), str(df.iat[i,10]), str(df.iat[i,11]), 
             str(df.iat[i,12])) 
        for i in range(len(df))]
    
        for i in progressbar(range(len(df)), "Computing: ", 40):
            time.sleep(0.1)            
            execute_concurrent_with_args(
                session,
                statement,
                parameters,
                concurrency=500
            )
        
            session.execute(batch)

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception("(cassandraDBLoad): Something went wrong in the CassandraDB Load operations\n" + str(e))
```

csv files link - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O03lNTMfSwhUKG61zOs7fNxXIRe44GRp?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Even with concurrent asynchronous requests (`execute_concurrent()`), it will still be bottlenecked on the client side because there is only so much a single client process can do even when it's multi-threaded.

If you want to maximise the throughput of your cluster, we recommend scaling your app horizontally and run multiple instances (processes). This can be easily achieved with the Python driver using the `multiprocessing` module. For details, see the [Python driver Performance Notes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/latest/performance/).

Finally, if your goal is to simply bulk-load data to your Cassandra DB, it makes no sense to re-invent the wheel by writing your own application when there are free, open-source tools that exist specifically for this use case.

You can use the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) tool (DSBulk) to bulk load data in CSV format to a Cassandra table. Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Eric!! Do you happen to have a tutorial/blog on how to use it with python?